# CodeIgniter custom caching

Tags: caching, codeigniter, outputcache

I would like to use the output caching function in CodeIgniter, it is simple & fast enough for my application. But the problem is CodeIgniter will push all cached files (hashed names) into the same folder, that will be a problem in my case where I have to cache about 150.000 static pages.

That huge number of the cached files does obviously slows down the process for each request. In my case, I can separate these static pages into multiple categories, so I am thinking of if I can handle CodeIgniter cache to work over the multiple cache folders, it would speed up the process.

Can anyone help me with any suggustion?

Thanks and regards,
Leo

Comment: How does having more files on disk slow down the request? CodeIgniter isn't going to spin through each file in the cache. It will only use the file the matches the request hash.

Comment: "That huge number of the cached files does obviously slows down the process for each request." - Is this merely an assumption or are you actually seeing this happen? If so, why would more directories help? As mentioned, CI doesn't just randomly sift through the cache files until it finds the one it's looking for.

Comment: Thanks you all for your replies. It is not my assumption at all, it is a problem I got and the reason for my question. Actually, I have an ext3 partition, it allows about 32K files in 1 directory. My application would require 5 times than that.

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31348860/1153296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to separate your cache files into subfolders, MP_Cache (http://hg.mijnpraktijk.com/mp_cache/overview) might help you. But be warned that MP_Cache is no longer maintained by the author.