# How To Create sub folder in cache Folder using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

```
class Caching extends CI_Controller { 

public function index() 
{ 
   $this->load->view('employee/index'); 
   $this->output->cache(15);
} 

}
```

I am able to create cache for index.php in cache folder, but I want to create a folder under cache/employee/cache file

creating Folder Dynamically based on which folder the view is calling

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify it in `application/config.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| system/cache/ folder.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['cache_path'] = 'var/www/site/public_html/application/cache/employee/cachefile';

//  ^ or whatever your server path to that folder is! ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to create subfolders in cache folder. So, you can modify system/helpers/file_helper.php

Function write_file() should be like this

```
function write_file($path, $data, $mode = FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE_DESTRUCTIVE)
{
    // Modifications here
    # Usage:
    # $this->cache->save('user/favourites/page1', $favourites);
    # Will create folder 'user/favourites' at cache folder and file 'page1' with data
    if (strpos($path, '/') !== false) {
        $folders = explode('/', $path);
        unset($folders[count($folders) - 1]);
        $dir = implode('/', $folders);
        mkdir($dir, 0744, TRUE);
    }
    // End of modifications

    if ( ! $fp = @fopen($path, $mode))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Or you can create file my_file_helper.php to "extend" system helper and override this function. This is much better solution.